# How do I get rid of the 'recently compared products' block on the the right column?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks

I have a 'Recently Compared Products' block on the right column on my categories pages. I cannot find a reference to this in the theme specific xml or phtml files, does this mean that it falls back to the default theme files? If so how do I remove this without altering the base files?

I'm running Magento 1.7 and the theme Foundation Framework.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans answer is right. But it has a small problem. It will remove the recently compared product block from every page. So if you want to use that feature any other page in Magento, then it is not going to work for you since you are removing the block entirely from almost every page.

So if  you want to remove this block only from category page, then you should use the appropriate layout handle. In your case this would work

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Comment: That's a more specific answer to my question, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<default>
    ...
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
    ...
</default>
```

Comment: That didn't work, it removes the Recently Viewed Products. However based on this, I managed to guess that this would work:
<remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />

Comment: And @CharlieRingo, did it work?

Comment: It absolutely did, thank you @Hans for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah correct, did read the wrong block name, apologize. I modified my answer with the correct block.

Answer (score 0):

```
<remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Please Accept Hans's answer if it helped you. Thanks